# Combination and Permutation Math Problem

Tags: permutations, combinations

I am having some difficulty dissecting this problem and solving it:

The track team has 7 girls and 6 boys. For the meet next week, they must choose a runner, a pole-vaulter, a captain and a time-keeper for a complete team. How many teams are possible.

1. if the team is restricted to have two girls and two boys.
2. if the team must have two boys.
3. if the team must have a boy as a captain and a girl as a runner.

I am not sure how to handle creating a team with specific positions for girls and boys.
What is the best approach for a scenario like this? A lot seems to be going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd give the solution to the first problem and hints to the next two. See if you can solve 2 and 3 (maybe you can post them as answers!) using the strategies for question 1.

There are two aspects to forming the team: we must pick 4 people within the 13 members to form the team (a combination aspect), and out of the 4 people we must designate the positions (a permutation aspect).

For Q1, since we must have two girls and two boys, let us pick them first. There are $\binom{7}{2}$ and $\binom{6}{2}$ ways to pick two girls and two boys respectively.

Now we have formed our team of 4. We need to designate the positions, and there are no restrictions imposed on the question for this part. Designating the positions is equivalent to ordering the four team members in a straight line, and we have $4!$ ways to do that.

Hence, by the multiplication principle, we have $\binom{7}{2} \times \binom{6}{2} \times 4!$ possible teams.

**Hints for Q2**: I'm interpreting the question to mean it must have at least 2 boys. It will be useful to break it up into cases (think of why we might want to do that):

- Case 1: 2 boys, 2 girls
- Case 2: 3 boys, 1 girl
- Case 3: 4 boys

Each case can be handled similar to Q1. We then use the addition principle to get the number of all the possible teams.

**Hints for Q3**: Since the restriction is on the captain and runner, let us first pick a captain (out of the boys) and a runner (out of the girls). We then pick a team of two from the remaining boys and girls with no restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

If the team must have 2 girls and 2 boys, then there are $\binom{7}{2}\cdot\binom{6}{2}=315$ ways to pick the team members. Then you have to assign them to their respective positions on the team, so for each of the $315$ you can pick your boys and girls you have $4$ choices for the runner, then $3$ choices for the pole-vaulter, then $2$ choices for the captain, and finally $1$ choice for the time-keeper.

Thus $315\cdot 24=7,560$ ways to choose two girls and two guys.

If the team must have two boys, I interpret that to mean at least two boys. You have to apply similar reasoning as above for the cases when you have three boys and four boys on the team and then add them all up.

Once you get going on this the third part should be easy.